# What's the "Impostor" dream job?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

[image]Has anyone else seen a worker show up in their "tiny death star" with "imposter" listed as their dream job? I've been playing for a few weeks on two devices, and never seen one before, however my son got one in his tds this evening (it was one of the blue-skinned aliens to boot). Where do imposters work?

Comment: BTW - If you hold down power and the home button simultaneously, it generates a screen shot.  Then the picture will be in your camera roll.  This way you won't need to post mirror pics!!!

Comment: LOL, I knew there was a simpler way - thanks for the tip!!!

Answer (score 4):

I just got a human like this, could it be that they have a dream job that does not yet exist? This morning it told me a sandwich store and something else had been added, but it still says 10/10 food levels, she's got the right font colour…

Edit: CONFIRMED
restart TDS and the dram job will be bongo sandwiches

Edit 2: in your case as recreation is higher than food, it'll probably be Planetarium instead

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I"m just noticing that the font color of "impostor" is green, yet the bitizen has higher skills in other level types. Never seen that before either (i.e. where its dream job skill level is lower than their skill in another non-dream category).

Comment: Confirmed it, see edit

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Looking forward to those new levels! (Not sure now, though if son will decide to evict the "impostor" before we find out where he really belongs. I talked him out of it just for curiosity's sake, but he's pretty ruthless..).

Comment: @user68997: The font color for Impostor seems to be always green, no matter what the actual dream job will be (my "Impostor" turned later into a different and blue dream later).

Answer (score 1):

I had the coolest thing happen with an Imposter level.

I added an Imperial level, and it became an Imposter level.
I just had to spend 100 Credits, and almost immediately it would earn 1 Imperial Service Medal. As I was trying to earn 985 of them for Service to the Empire rewards, I kept collecting more and more of them and eventually earned R2-Q5.

Now that Imposter Imperial level changed into the new Trooper Barracks level.
I noticed at the same time that I have a bitizen who wants to work at Imposter, but now it has changed to a different new level I don't own yet: Cloth Fabricator

So it seems that Imposter levels can be Imperial or Shops.
I'm sure I couldn't have taken my bitizen down to the Imperial level, but maybe if I had built some sort of retail level instead, I could have delivered him there as others have reported. As it was, I scored a ton of Imperial Service medals and a couple rewards.

Answer (score 0):

Or it'll be a dream job for Imperial Marches ;) it appears that the added dream jobbers for the Limited floor as well. I got one anyway

Comment: That'd be neat. Will let you all know (if my son doesn't lose patience and evict him in the meantime). :(

Comment: Imperial Marches have their own dream jobbers, as do Panna City Medicines. I've gotten 2 but jettisoned them coz they were only skill 6.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got a guy with the job, and then got the level. I built one of the new residential levels and it turned into a green shop that sold Impostor 0. I got a buck for getting the guy to the shop. After a restart, the level became Apartments and the guy was gone. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Found an imposter as well.  Rebooted the app and a bunch of new levels showed up in my list of build able levels.  The imposter's dream job changed to Kashyyk Shack (purple).  Seems like another "bug" since I can't build any of the lnew levels even though they are in the list.

New levels: RES: Endor ARMS, Csilla APTS, Wookie ARMS / REC: Endor Adventure

DIFFERENT SUBJECT: I'm getting tired of the constant changing of build values / time to complete for the imperial levels

STOP CHANGING THE RULES NIMBLEBIT!

Answer (score 0):

I also had somebody with dream job "Impostor" (in green). After a while (maybe restarting the game) it turned into "CHISS HSP", and it stayed that way. As in [this other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/156570/66181), it is a level I don't own yet.

Moreover, unlike most level (and like Imperial Marches, Endor Adventure, Kashyyyk Shack, and a few apartment levels) this one cannot be unlocked with imperial bux — but that seems not a rule, since I would be able to unlock Bongo sandwiches, yet in [this yet other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/155584/66181) the Impostor dream job turned into "Bongo sandwiches".